# Global.asax Application_Error equivalent in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, startup, event-log

I am trying to catch errors from my .NET application before they are written to the event log. I have seen in the accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824581/how-to-disable-net-event-log-warnings) question that the way to do it would be to include an `Application_Error` (or `Application_OnError` it says) function in the Global.asax.

However, we have switched to using Startup.cs only now, and can't work out how to make the equivalent call. The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168978/do-i-need-a-global-asax-cs-file-at-all-if-im-using-an-owin-startup-cs-class-and) question suggests that it may not be possible. Does anyone know for sure if there is an equivalent way to handle these errors?

Comment: use [elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/elmah/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By saying you've "switched to using Startup" I'm assuming you mean using an OWIN pipeline.

`Application_Error` only gets called when an exception is thrown during a request, and is unhandled.

So the equivalent in an OWIN pipeline is to catch any unhandled exceptions at the start of your OWIN pipeline.

In other words you need to create a custom middle-ware with a `try`/`catch` around the call to `_next` and then you can do what you want with the exception in the catch clause.

[This other StackOverlow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28688662/how-to-override-default-unhandled-exception-output-in-owin#28689030) shows how it is done.